# Changes to tag Wiki gone missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just edited a previously empty tag Wiki and put a good deal of effort into writing a decent description, providing an example etc. in a reasonable length. I saved it, got the usual "Thanks for the edit, we will review it" message and then waited for a while but nothing happened. When I returned to the tag Wiki later my text had completely disappeared. Now I'm just wondering what happened there?
I'm sure what was written was not wrong and it certainly was an improvement (given that this tag had been empty before), so I asked myself if this is a bug of some sort?

Comment: Which tag is it?

Comment: It was the effect-size tag. But thanks to whuber's answer I know now what went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently reviewed several tag wikis and wiki excerpts that you proposed.  Some I accepted, others I accepted with edits, and a few others--including one long one--I declined.  In all cases I provided explicit reasons. **Thus, if there is any bug here it would be that those reasons were not communicated back to you by the system.**

To hunt down what's going on, I looked at your recent user activity (available on your profile page) and linked through the "suggested edit" links.  That brought me to pages like the one at https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24893, where at the top my response is prominently highlighted:

> Rejected 24 mins ago:
>
> whuber♦ reviewed this 24 mins ago: Reject
>
> This text goes well beyond what would be needed in a wiki: consider posing a question that it would answer and then post this as an answer.

Therefore **it appears that all is working,** although it seems like the system for providing feedback for rejected edits could be streamlined.

---

Incidentally, the suggested edit is still visible at https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24893.

Comment: I edited several of Andy's tag efforts myself, in an effort to make them a bit closer to typical tag wiki entries. Andy; if you look around it's generally not hard to find exactly who did what when. If you think someone has acted wrongly you can always raise it here. However, if anything people are very reluctant to reject well intentioned efforts, so it's usually for very good reason. (Tag wikis don't offer a chance for more than a few words of comment when editing or rejecting; reasoning and disagreements can be more easily clarified in comments on posts)

Comment: No you're right, I didn't think that whuber or someone else did something wrong - in fact the mods are doing a really good job here. I was just not aware of where to find the response given that the system doesn't notify users of these kinds of decisions. Now I know where to find them.